# How can I learn to read formulas with greek symbols?

Tags: algorithm, math

I suppose maybe it's because I don't know the keywords to google for, but I can't find any sources on how to read those formulas you see on wikipedia, like this for instance:
[Erlang Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution)

I've searched in the math world and computer science world. It feels like it is assumed that we're supposed to understand it out of thin air. Beginner lessons seem scarce.

So far I know how sigma works. And that upside-down shape that is used as the half-life logo is called lambda. But what the heck is it trying to say?? Why is there a semi-colon in the function, etc..

If there is a book on this stuff I'd buy it in an instant. It is probably very basic stuff but I never had experience in theoretical math or even know where to look.

Does anyone know what this subject is called, and what to google for?

Comment: Maths texts usually explain what the symbols signify. You should probably learn their names using e.g. wikipedia.

Comment: A good palce to start is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_notation#Notation

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the colon in alt.: \scriptstyle \theta \;=\; \frac{1}{\lambda} > 0\, scale (real) in the box in Wikipedia is just saying that there is an alternative definition, in which you specify theta rather than lambda, and in that definition what is called theta is the reciprocal of lambda in the other definition.

I once complained to a much better mathematician than I was that I came unstuck with formulas with some of the weirder greek letters in because I couldn't write them recognisably in my handwriting (which is bad enough for the latin alphabet). He said a lot of the people he knew simply said "let x be funny-squiggle-thing" and rewrote with sensible letters. I really wish I'd thought of that.

In general, letters in weird alphabets behave pretty much like sensible letters, at least in the sort of thing you are pointing at. It's done as a sort of type-checking - usually all of the letters pinched from some particular foreign language are related in some way - e.g. all parameters. Unfortunately that doesn't hold exactly in the Wikipedia example you quote, where two of the greek letters stand for functions - one is definitely the Gamma function. I suspect the other is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2):

Formulas with this symbols usually are statistics or probability notations.
Greek letters (e.g. θ, β) are commonly used to denote unknown parameters (population parameters).

Greek letters used in mathematics, science, and engineering
[you can find info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_letters_used_in_mathematics,_science,_and_engineering)

Notation in probability and statistics
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the resources list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is still searching in Google (or other search engine, whatever float your boat) about the specific formula you are trying to learn. Sometimes a symbol may be used in different meaning in different formula.

Anyway, there is a good resource in [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm) that explained a lot of math symbols, not just the Greek symbol.

Some link that may interest you [here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Common_Math_Symbols.pdf) and [here](http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/math-results-and-formulas/math-symbols.html).

Comment: It's rather tricky to search for the meaning of f(x;y,n) if you don't know the names for the terms

Answer (score 0):

First, find a Greek alphabet (upper and lower case) to refer to, so that you can at least call lambda by it's name.  No one starts out knowing automatically what the various Greek characters are, not even Greeks.

Second, Read the actual article, usually either the character is defined (as lambda happens to be in the Wikipedia page you references) or it's standard nomenclature (in which case you've done the right thing by looking for a basic article on the function in question-- I do this *all the time* so don't feel bad.)  Or, as a third option, it's a crappy paper.  Happens sometimes.  It's kind of a pain, though, since you can't just do a text search on the lambda character in a PDF.

(Someone educate me on that if I'm wrong....)

Third, try to pick out which unfamiliar symbols are variables (like lambda) and which are operators (like sigma, and it's helpers.)  It's the operators that can sometimes cause real trouble.  A variable is just a name for something, but operators come freighted with more meaning, more rules, and more syntax.  It's not always obvious which symbols are operators, either.

Finally, and specifically for computer science, a good introductory book (college freshman/sophomore level) on discrete math will hopefully treat most of the basic notations and operators to at least get your feet on the ground.  Nowadays, you kids and your newfangled internet might be able to get something similar from Udacity, Edx, Course RA, or the Khan Academy.

Basically, it's a lot of hard work, especially on your own, but you're already doing most of the right things.